# Hodoop namenode not starting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

When I use start-all.cmd, then datanode, resourcemanager, nodemanager are working properly but namenode is not working!

```
19/11/04 22:09:14 WARN namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:634)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:695)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:898)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:877)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1603)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1671)
19/11/04 22:09:14 INFO mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:50070
19/11/04 22:09:14 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
19/11/04 22:09:14 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
19/11/04 22:09:14 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
19/11/04 22:09:14 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:634)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:695)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:898)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:877)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1603)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1671)
19/11/04 22:09:14 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
19/11/04 22:09:14 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's much better if you share your non-working code as a minimal reproducible example so that the proposed solution actually applies to your problem and can help future visitors with the same problem. Otherwise, there's a high likelihood that people will be tossing out random solutions that might not help you (or anyone else) much. See How to Ask and take the tour for more information on how to ask an on-topic question

Answer (score 2):

1. Open **cmd** as **administrator.**
2. Type and run `stop-all.cmd`
3. Then run `hadoop namenode –format`
4. Finally run `start-all.cmd`

Hope it will work for you.